# Managing parallel processes

Tags: perl, parallel-processing

I am starting multiple bash scripts from a Perl script and I want to monitor them and log their behavior.

I know that I can tell whether a process is still running with `kill 0, $pid` and I can get the exit code from `$?`, but with launching multiple scripts in the background I can't relate values of `$?` to the processes that gave it as an exit code.

How can I launch those scripts in parallel, but get the exit code from each them? I need something like [`proc_get_status`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php) from PHP.

Sorry for not providing the code from the beginning.
I stripped down the code, so the important things are to see.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use IPC::Open3;
use IO::Handle;

my $timeLimit = 60*60; # some time limit not to be crossed
my $startTime = time();

my @commands  = (); # fill up with commands to be executed
my @processes = ();

foreach my $cmd (@commands) {
  my $stdout = IO::Handle->new;
  my $stderr = IO::Handle->new;
  my $pid = open3(undef, $stdout, $stderr, $cmd);
  push @processes, {"pid" => $pid, "out" => $stdout, "err" => $stderr, "cmd" => $fullcmd};
}

do {
  if (time() - $startTime > $timeLimit) {
    kill 2, $_->{pid} foreach (@processes);
    @processes = ();
    last;
  } else {
    for (my $i = 0; $i < @processes; $i++) {
      unless (kill 0, $processes[$i]) {
        # if it's not running, I would like to check the exit code and log it from here on.
        # also remove it from the array, thats why I used for and not foreach, so I can use splice later.
      }
    }
  }
} while (@processes > 0);
```

Comment: where is the code you wrote, which you are having the issues with? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50292129/edit) your question and add your attempt.

Comment: Everything depends on *how* you are starting these processes in parallel. We can't do a thing without seeing your code.

Comment: I added the code now. If you find some mistakes, it's because I just stripped it down and didn't test it.

Comment: I suggest that you make use of [`IPC::Run`](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.99/lib/IPC/Run.pm) instead of `IPC:;Open3`: it is much more comprehensive and provides a specific `results` method to retrieve the exit status.

Comment: It looks like you don't read from the child's STDOUT and STDERR until after they exit, in which case the child could block until killed by timeout.

Comment: Can you use code from GNU Parallel which is written in Perl?

Answer (score 1):

You have already hit upon the insight of storing background job data in mini-objects. Take the next step and try a full-featured parallelization package like [`Forks::Super`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super). You can create background process objects that you can then query for their [status](https://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super::Job#is_%3Cstate%3E) and [exit code](https://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super::Job#status,-exit_status). `Forks::Super` supports [process timeouts](https://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super#timeout) and an [`open3`-like interface](https://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super#open3).

```
use Forks::Super;
$Forks::Super::MAX_PROC = 10;   # optional, block while 10 jobs already running

...

foreach my $cmd (@commands) {
    my $job = fork {
         cmd => $cmd,              # run $cmd in background process
         child_fh => 'out,err',    # child STDOUT,STDERR available to parent
         timeout => $timeLimit     # kill the job after $timeLimit seconds
    };
    push @processes, $job;
}

while (@processes) {
    sleep 5;
    foreach my $job (@processes) {
        if ($job->is_complete) {
            $job->wait;
            my $exit_code = $job->status;
            my $output = $job->read_stdout;
            my $error = $job->read_stderr;
            # ... log status, output, error, $job->{cmd}, etc. ...
            $job->dispose;     # close filehandles and other clean up
        }
    }
    @processes = grep { !$_->is_reaped } @processes;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't waiting to call `read_stdout` and `read_stderr` until after the child finishes means you can deadlock? I don't see any documentation that F::S empties the pipes in the background, so it's a definite possibility.

Comment: In general F::S communicates through temporary files to get around that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait and waitpid to get the status of individual children. The [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) documentation gives a few examples in the section on "Signals".

Since you're using IPC::Open3, the Synopsis also has an example of using waitpid():

```
    my($wtr, $rdr, $err);
    use Symbol 'gensym'; $err = gensym;
    $pid = open3($wtr, $rdr, $err,
            'some cmd and args', 'optarg', ...);

    waitpid( $pid, 0 );
    my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;
```

Answer (score -1):

First, take a look at Perl's `fork()` function. This would be the typical way I do things like this. There's a good explanation with examples [here](https://perlmaven.com/fork).

An easy to use forking module is provided by [Parallel::ForkManger](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.5/ForkManager.pm).

There is also Perl's [interpreter-base threads](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) which is a bit lower-level, harder to use, and spawns threads rather than forking processes.

Another possible way is with [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). `parallel` is a very powerful tool to run commands in parallel. You can easily run and manage multiple commands and scripts with it. It has a `---joblog` option which might be helpful for you.

All of these approaches provide ways to get the exit code of the sub-processes. In the end, the best choice depends on your current implementation which you did not provide.

Comment: This simply lists ways of executing processes in parallel; it doesn't answer the question at all. The OP says that they have already achieved the parallelism and is asking how to *manage* the processes.

Comment: I provided examples of several common approaches which allow for, getting the exit code and managing child processes within perl.

Comment: *"approaches which allow for, getting the exit code and managing child processes within perl"* Do they? You didn't say so in your post, and you you certainly didn't show *how*, which would have answered the question. You just dumped four ways you know to run stuff in parallel.